# Apache Server Side Includes - JSP WLS Plugin

Tags: apache, ssi, server-side-includes

I am running Apache 249 and attempting to use SSI via a weblogic application.

I have added the following lines to my config file.

```
AddType text/html .jsp
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .jsp
```

And have added the `Options Includes` both to the `virtualHost` and below.

```
<Directory "/apache/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes 
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

If I acces a test SSI file from within `/apache/htdocs` it works fine, however if I use a `Location` block using the Weblogic Plugin it doesn't work.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `SetOutputFilter Includes` within your Location Block that will process the .jsp file from the proxy before passing to the client, allowing the Virtual Include to work.